# Image restoration using java

Tags: image-processing, java

i am working in digital image restoration field, i am familiar with java and i want to use java in **image restoration**, can any please suggest me any book or tutorials where i can learn about image restoration using java.

I have already checked this [java tutorial](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/blurring.html)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Java as such would offer exceptional advantages to Image Restoration as such.

If you are comfortable using Java and want to use it as a development tool, using ImageJ as a library would be a good starting step.